# Moving window with mouse and hotkey in MacOS

Tags: macos, window, mouse, move, hotkeys

Is there a way to move window with a mouse after clicking on window (any zone) holding some key like **command** / **control** / **alt** in **MacOS X Lion**?

So the process is like:

1. you click on a window while holding **command**
2. do not leave the mouse button, **move** mouse
3. with mouse selected window is moving

I had this option in Linux and that was very useful.

Thanks.

Comment: I wish this had an answer out of the box ... maybe now that its 5 years later it does ?  ... linux is extremely handy with anything developer centric ... like this question

Comment: see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321918/move-window-by-clicking-on-any-part-as-on-linux/365860#365860

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coming from someone who also got very used to this functionality under Linux, I also spent some time looking for a tool to do this after getting a Mac. I don't believe that this is possible out of the box.

I use a product named [Hyperdock (9.95 USD)](http://hyperdock.bahoom.com/) to facilitate this. In addition to some other functionality that I don't use (window previews, iTunes extensions, etc), it includes options for moving and resizing windows with left mouse button + hotkey. It's not free, but it's the only tool I've been able to find that provides this functionality.